# How to add CORS headers to 401/403 responses?

Tags: angular, cors, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have build an spa website with Angular on the front end and asp.net Core Web Api 3.0 on the server side.

I am trying to configure Windows Authentication, thanks to [this article](https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angular-4-3-1-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api/) so far so good! However... there is a problem with CORS headers when the Api correctly returns a 401/403, the cors headers are missing. Here is an example:

```
General:
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: [::1]:44389
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response-Headers:
Date: Wed, 20 Nov 2019 16:33:57 GMT
Persistent-Auth: true
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

This is what is generated when I use the `[Authorise]` attribute. The problem I have is, when the CORS headers are missing, the Status code within angular is 0 so my http intercepters are unaware of the unauthorisation and cannot handle the redirect properly.

I have tried manually adding the headers using middleware within the `StartUp`:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });

    await next();
});
```

but this does not work, the middle ware still removes the headers.

Interestingly, if I remove the authorise attribute and return a 401/403 within the controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
    => Unauthorized();
```

The CORS headers are returned as so:

```
Response-Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

This is not feasable!

**Does anyone know how to ensure the CORS headers are persisted by the Authorise middleware?**

Comment: does your web server and API server different or running on different port ?

Comment: Yes they are running on seperate ports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out everything was configured correctly, well almost!

The issue was simply the order in which the middle ware was configured in the `StartUp` class. I did not know the order in which the middle ware was configured had an effect on the execution. This was my original code:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication()
   .UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                      .AllowCredentials()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

Configuring Cors **BEFORE** Authentication fixed the problem, now unauthorized requests handled by the middle ware still includes the cors headers.

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                                      .AllowCredentials()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader());
app.UseAuthentication()
   .UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this, I was getting crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to post a copy of the complete startup.cs file?  I have the same problem and followed your changes but still receiving 401.  Im trying to access a site on IIS 10 that is set to windows authentication.